# Likes won't added

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I put a like button on my own website and when I click, my website is added to facebook as news feeds displaying that I likes a website, but it is no added to my profile Likes: Here the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

meta properties:

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Puerto Deseado Turismo" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Puerto Deseado Turismo: Agencia de viajes y turismo nacional e internacional. Contamos con transportacion propia con unidades 2012" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.puertodeseadoevyt.com.ar/index.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.puertodeseadoevyt.com.ar/images/logo-pd-facebook.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Puerto Deseado Turismo" />
</head>
```

and the iframe:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.puertodeseadoevyt.com.ar&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

What is missing?

Comment: If you want a like to show on a user's profile, you need to create a Facebook Page for your website and like the URL of the Facebook page.

Comment: Are you sure? likes of URLs should appear under 'other pages' in the profile list of likes; they do for me anyway

Comment: Hello lgy, When I click on my webiste on the Like button, it is displayed on my facebook list of likes, but the image of the logo doesn't appear, and too the image on the year calendar doesn't appear.